# Java find intersection of two lines

Tags: java, math, geometry, line, point

In Java, I have a class `Line` that has two variables : `m` and `b`, such that the line follows the formula `mx + b`. I have two such lines. How am I to find the `x` and `y` coordinates of the intersection of the two lines? (Assuming the slopes are different)

Here is `class Line`:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public final class Line {
    public final double m, b;

    public Line(double m, double b) {
        this.m = m;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Point intersect(Line line) {
        double x = (this.b - line.b) / (this.m - line.m);
        double y = this.m * x + this.b;
        return new Point((int) x, (int) y);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, int startx, int endx, int width, int height) {
        startx -= width / 2;
        endx -= width / 2;
        int starty = this.get(startx);
        int endy = this.get(endx);
        Point points = Format.format(new Point(startx, starty), width, height);
        Point pointe = Format.format(new Point(endx, endy), width, height);
        g.drawLine(points.x, points.y, pointe.x, pointe.y);
    }

    public int get(int x) {
        return (int) (this.m * x + this.b);
    }

    public double get(double x) {
        return this.m * x + this.b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Youve got code there already: Does it not work? Also, think about what you would do on pen and paper with 2 y=mx+b lines if you were trying to solve them. Equate and solve for x to define a general solution for x and then use either lines equation to solve for y. Translate the formulas to code

Comment: Are you having trouble figuring out the formula?  That's [math.se].  Or are you having trouble translating your known formula into code?  That shouldn't be too hard, and is already done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets assume you have these 2 functions:

```
y = m1*x + b1    
y = m2*x + b2
```

To find the intersection point of the `x-axis` we do:

```
m1*x+b1 = m2*x+b2    
m1*x-m2*x = b2 - b2    
x(m1-m2) = (b2-b1)    
x = (b2-b1) / (m1-m2)
```

To find y, you use of the function expressions and replace `x` for its value `(b2-b1) / (m1-m2)`.

So:

```
y = m1 * [(b2-b1) / (m1-m2)] + b1
```

You have `(this.b - line.b)`, change to `(line.b - this.b)`.

```
public Point intersect(Line line) {
    double x = (line.b - this.b) / (this.m - line.m);
    double y = this.m * x + this.b;

    return new Point((int) x, (int) y);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I thought it was just a little error since my numbers were small. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just be aware, this solution doesn't work for vertical and parallel lines. In case of `m-line.m=0` it is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution by @[wutzebaer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131857/wutzebaer) seems not to work, instead try the solution below (code based on the example from: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_the_intersection_of_two_lines#Java). 
s1 and s2 are the endpoints of the first line and d1 and d2 are the endpoints of the second line.

```
public static Point2D.Float calculateInterceptionPoint(Point2D.Float s1, Point2D.Float s2, Point2D.Float d1, Point2D.Float d2) {

        double a1 = s2.y - s1.y;
        double b1 = s1.x - s2.x;
        double c1 = a1 * s1.x + b1 * s1.y;

        double a2 = d2.y - d1.y;
        double b2 = d1.x - d2.x;
        double c2 = a2 * d1.x + b2 * d1.y;

        double delta = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;
        return new Point2D.Float((float) ((b2 * c1 - b1 * c2) / delta), (float) ((a1 * c2 - a2 * c1) / delta));

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(calculateInterceptionPoint(new Point2D.Float(3, 5), new Point2D.Float(0, 2), new Point2D.Float(1, 2), new Point2D.Float(4, 0)));

}
```

Comment: Yep! This solution is working! Upvoted! Thanks!

Comment: For the input parameters you can also use two `Line2D.Float` (fields: x1, y1, x2, y2).

Answer (score 1):

That's what i got. Couldn't find any exeptions which don't work:

```
public static Point calculateInterceptionPoint(Point s1, Point d1, Point s2, Point d2) {

    double sNumerator = s1.y * d1.x + s2.x * d1.y - s1.x * d1.y - s2.y * d1.x;
    double sDenominator = d2.y * d1.x - d2.x * d1.y;

    // parallel ... 0 or infinite points, or one of the vectors is 0|0
    if (sDenominator == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    double s = sNumerator / sDenominator;

    double t;
    if (d1.x != 0) {
        t = (s2.x + s * d2.x - s1.x) / d1.x;
    } else {
        t = (s2.y + s * d2.y - s1.y) / d1.y;
    }

    Point i1 = new Point(s1.x + t * d1.x, s1.y + t * d1.y);

    return i1;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calculateInterceptionPoint(new Point(3, 5), new Point(0, 2), new Point(1, 2), new Point(4, 0)));
    System.out.println(calculateInterceptionPoint(new Point(3, 5), new Point(0, 2), new Point(1, 2), new Point(0, 2)));
    System.out.println(calculateInterceptionPoint(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 2), new Point(0, 0), new Point(2, 0)));
    System.out.println(calculateInterceptionPoint(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 2), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 2)));
    System.out.println(calculateInterceptionPoint(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0)));
}
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate a Point object with double coordinations in the constructor; you should create one empty object and then populate it. The constructor only accepts int values.

Comment: In any case the implementation seems wrong to me. Math doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(calculateIntersection()));
  }

  public static double[] calculateIntersection() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The program calculates the point of intersection of two lines, given by their equations: ax + b. Please introduce the a and b coefficients of both lines:");

    double m1 = scanner.nextInt();
    double b1 = scanner.nextInt();
    double m2 = scanner.nextInt();
    double b2 = scanner.nextInt();

    if ((m2 - m1) == 0) {
      throw new ArithmeticException("The lines don't have intersection, because they're parallel.");
    }

    // Intersection [x,y] formula
    double crossX = (b1 - b2) / (m2 - m1);
    double crossY = (m1 * crossX + b1);

    double[] array = new double[] {crossX,crossY};
    return array;
  }
}
```