# How to get the intersection of two lines on android studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I've been looking how to get the intersection point of two lines in android studio, I need to create and draw on the screen, polygons with those points of intersection to get their area. I've tried with android studio built in Canvas but it doesn't seem to get the intersections of any other object but rectangles, is there any way i can do this?

Comment: If you have the start/end points of the lines you can solve this problem with a mathematical equation. Have you already tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31506840/6691953

Comment: that's a great idea, but i need to draw them on the screen, any way i could do both things?

Comment: Sure. Check out this post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android :)